# generate sha256 with german character in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic

I use this implementation of the sha256 algorithm in a classic asp project: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2565

This works fine. But I noticed that if the password has a german character like 'ü' in it, the hash is different. I can reproduce it with if I just call the sha method with a ü inside. I assume there is some encoding issue, but all my tries to set a proper encoding didn't work.
Does someone has an idea?

Thanks
NPadrutt

Comment: This article is a good place to start - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I used it to ensure that the data is displayed correctly. But the hash is still different for some reason. If I compare them:

ü:
607474ca475a9724d7360aba71a56d5df77e61350e3f724cfa1f46e857e2d85f

hashed in asp classic:
98722e2ebed8ed3d3652e11e4181f0dccc1ce7d192d8f1db370af8ec4a4e174a

but if I do the same with u there are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. As something like a pseudo salt I reverse the password string. and attach it to the original string.

ReversedString + String

The problem here is that something like a 'ü' is display with this: Ã¼
If I reverse the string it also reverses this to: ¼Ã. In C# it handles this correctly..